# Mediation ads ain't showing up in simulator , Giving Cannot find an ad network adapter with the name

Tags: ios, admob, mobile-ad-mediation

The exact error is this:

> Cannot find an ad network adapter with the name(s):
>   com.google.ads.mediation.admob.AdMobAdapter. Remember to link all
>   required ad network adapters and SDKs, and set -ObjC in the 'Other
>   Linker Flags' setting of your build target.

I am using Swift and I have installed adapters and SDK for Vungle, Mopub, and Milennial, but its always giving me this error. Other error is below:

> Cannot find an ad network adapter with the name(s):
>   com.mopub.mobileads.dfp.adapters.MoPubAdapter. Remember to link all
>   required ad network adapters and SDKs, and set -ObjC in the 'Other
>   Linker Flags' setting of your build target.

Comment: Did you add the ObjC linked flag to your build target?

Comment: @Nik Yes I did.

Comment: Did you add it to target or project? Also, try removing (deleting), then re-adding the problematic adapters. Make sure you enable "Copy items if needed"

Comment: @Nik have you faced the same problem?

Comment: Yes, however there are a few things that maybe causing this error

Comment: @Nik could it be possible due to some thing at backend , because client is giving me ad id's. I am using 3 mediation networks . Vungle , Millenial Media and MoPub.

Comment: Do you only get these 2 errors, or do you get more similar errors? Try the app on a real device and see what happens there. See what I said earlier about re-adding the problematic adapters properly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are getting these kind of errors then check your setup in admob console. Your project may be created for android platform. This was the problem in my case.

Happy Coding.